# deny activating the menu by clicking around it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my site i have a menu that has certain functionalities and animation:

- On mouse rollover there's a change in opacity for all elements of the menu except the one that is hovered above.
- When clicking on an element, it's marked by keeping its color and reducing the opacity of non-clicked elements.
- When an element is clicked the menu shift to the left (solved)
- A slider fades in when clicking on an element. (solved)

Now all these functions are working great, however the problem is that they can be all activated by clicking around the menu and above it, and not only on the elements.
Can it be fixed so that all the functions(without changing them) are activated just by clicking on an element in the menu?

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/atkumqpk/1/

html of the menu:

```
<div id="menu" class="menu">
    <ul class="headlines">
        <li id="item1">
            <button>aaaaaaaa</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item2">
            <button>bbbbbbb</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item3">
            <button>ccccccc</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item4">
            <button>dddddddd</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item5">
            <button>eeeeeee eee.</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item6">
            <button>ffffff</button>
        </li>
        <li id="item7">
            <button>ggggggg</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a CSS issue. If you check your `li` elements in a DOMInspector you'll see that they are huge. You just need to make them smaller after they have been slid to the left.

Comment: Did it start to work on your Chrome? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31206604/4365626)?

Comment: @VibhorDube no...  only after i re-size, but it's not related to the menu activation problem, which i had from the beginning

Comment: you could instead of changing the size of the `li` elements just move the id to the buttons, they should be much smaller

Answer (score 0):

In your js there is a function:

```
$(".menu").on("click", function () {
    $(".menu").addClass('permahover');

});
```

Change the activator to `.menu button` :

```
$(".menu button").on("click", function () {
    $(".menu").addClass('permahover');

});
```

## Update

I suggest spend some time and read about common CSS methodologies. Same applies for your use of JQuery.

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atkumqpk/10/). Made a couple of changes but long story short, wherever you apply some style/animation/action to your `<li>` tags, this should be to their `<button>` children.

Take a closer look at the css changes here:

```
.headlines:hover li button, .headlines.active li button
.headlines button:hover, .headlines li button.active
```

Comment: this solution solved the fade in/out and animation to the left.. But where to apply it for the hovering and for the permenant change in opacity, the other two functions mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

This is rather an imperfect solution, but is a start. CSS could be handled better here overall. You may check this in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chixieburr/oakgu3nc/).

```
.menu li {
position: relative;
/*top: 180px;
left: 0px;*/
}
.headlines li {
width:auto;margin-left: 0 !important
}
```

The hover instance and click function should trigger the other div to appear on the 'li block' or the button itself.

Comment: but what about the animation shifting to the left